# transfer the data with vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an Excel file in which, according to the code below, the data from sheet 1 is transferred between sheets 2, 3 and 4.
For this purpose, I used data cut from sheet 1, which causes all the formulas of sheet 1 to be deleted and the new data that I enter are without formulas. In your opinion, how do you cut the data without deleting the formula in sheet 1? did
Or can copy be used instead of cut, while the previously transferred data will not be moved between the sheets and only the new data will be moved?

````
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, mycell As Range
    Dim n As Long, ci As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   
    For n = 3 To 916
        Set mycell = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").cells(n, 1)
        ci = 0
        If mycell >= 24 Then
            ci = 4
            Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
        ElseIf mycell.Value >= 12 Then
            ci = 5
            Set ws = Sheets("Sheet3")
        ElseIf Len(mycell) > 0 Then ' skip blanks
            ci = 6
            Set ws = Sheets("Sheet4")
        End If
        If ci > 0 Then
            mycell.Interior.ColorIndex = ci
            mycell.Resize(1, 16).Cut _
               Destination:=ws.cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    For n = 2 To 4
        wb.Sheets("Sheet" & n).Columns.AutoFit
    Next
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub ```
````

Comment: "how do you cut the data without deleting the formula in sheet 1" Cutting means that the cells will be empty whether or not they contain formulas. If you copy, the cell contents in sheet 1 remain. Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: `mycell.Resize(1, 16).Copy` then next line `ws.cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: If I use copy, when I add new data to sheet 1, then the previous data will be duplicated again to sheets 2, 3, and 4, while the previous data was already copied, and I don't want to have duplicate data in the following sheets.